# Django form.save()

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have some problems with [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) in Django. I can't add an object to the database.

#### File *views.py*

```python
@login_required
def persons_add(request):
    form = forms.PersonForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('persons_list')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'persons/persons_add.html', context)
```

#### File *form.html*

```html
<form role="form" method="POST" action="/persons/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <tr>
            <th>
                {{ field.label }}
            </th>
            <td>
                {{ field }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Person</button>
</form>
```

#### File *forms.py*

```python
from django import forms

from persons import models

class PersonForm (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Person
        fields = ['name', 'surname']
```

#### File *person_list.html*

```html
<tbody>
    {% for person in persons_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.surname }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ person.id }}/edit"
               <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></p>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ person.id }}/delete">
                <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></p>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

#### File *urls.py* (application)

```python
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from persons import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #url(r'^$', views.PersonsView.as_view(), name='persons'),
    url(r'^$', views.persons_list, name='persons_list'),
    url(r'^add/', views.persons_add, name="persons_add"),
    url(r'^(?P<person_id>\d+)/edit/$', views.persons_edit, name="persons_edit"),
    url(r'^(?P<person_id>\d+)/delete/$', views.persons_delete, name="persons_delete"),
)
```

#### File *urls.py* (main project)

```python
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from hr import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^persons/', include('persons.urls', namespace='persons')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
)
```

Where is the bug? Why is nothing working here? Why can't I send POST to database and add *Person*?

Comment: Try changing your form action to post to `/persons/add/`

Comment: ok! I have the post to datebase, I check in panel admin, now I need to put them on web list

Comment: Please check my updates, correct your `urls.py` as well.

Comment: if that's helped you solve *this* question, I'd like you to accept my answer and move on to post a new question **IF** you have tried and read enough from the Django document. These are considered the basics of Django and everything is pretty much well covered. You should follow their example, do thing one at a time. Eventually you will understand how the elements work together

Comment: I pull Your changes, it's working like before. Now i have `NoReverseMatch` so I have to change urls to repair this. Can You explane me, why when I change post to '/persons/add/' it send POST, but when I hade '/persons/' it didn't send it?

Comment: That is because your form post **action** is where the *POST* request should send, in your **urls** you define `/persons/` as `persons_list`, and it is not supposed to handle a form post. That's why when you change to `/persons/add/` the correct route, the form can be handled by your `views`, and thus model is saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there are mistakes in your `views`. You need to send the empty form on a **[GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)** request, and handle the form when it's **[POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29)**:

```
@login_required
def persons_add(request):
    # Check if it's POST request then handle the form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.PersonForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('persons_list')
    else:
        # If not, you need an empty form for GET request
        form = forms.PersonForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'persons/persons_add.html', context)
```

Correct this first and then we will check again where you are, one step at a time.

Check your **url** route. You're currently posting to `/persons/`. Change to `/persons/add/` as your **url** suggested.

Also, there is mistake in your main *urls.py* file. If you want to **include** application **urls.py**, do not mix with your main routes. Split them like this:

Main *urls.py* file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
)

# Split your app URLs and using += patterns with their views
urlpatterns += patterns(
    'persons.views',
    (r'^persons/', include('persons.urls', namespace='persons')),
)
```

Comment: I correct this, but it doesn't help. I check server request, and I get this:

[22/Jan/2015 23:51:23] "GET /persons/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2161
[22/Jan/2015 23:51:29] "POST /persons/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10335

So nothing has change....hmmmm.....

Comment: @Chris, this is only part of the mistakes, there are another, you should show the **error** fields as well, and use a **<input>** element for submit (well you should, not must). Also, what about your model? Is there other fields which are **required**??

Comment: @Chris, also, what's your **url** routes like? You're posting to `/persons/`... is this correct, have you checked?

Comment: Nope, I work only on this model to learn more django. 
[name = models.CharField(max_length=30)]
    [surname = models.CharField(max_length=30)]